# Selecting in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I  have table

```
ID       Name        Book   
1        Aaron       HTML
2        Charles     DESIGN
3        Mark        SQL
4        Charles     JAVA
5        Charles     C++ 
6        Mark        C#
```

I want to `SELECT` the rows with the greatest `ID` per  `Name`, having a result is like this:

```
ID       Name        Book   
1        Aaron       HTML
5        Charles     C++ 
6        Mark        C#
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By _last row_, you mean you want the row with the greatest `ID` per `Name`?

Comment: Yes. the row with the greatest ID per Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, but should work:

```
select * from [mytable] where id in 
  (select max(id) as id from mytable group by name)
```

Comment: The subquery is going to cause problems because it selects _two_ columns instead of one.

Comment: I try and I got an error like Michael Berkowski said.

Comment: try with edit, should work w/out the extra column in the sub-query...typing too fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` function with a `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT ID, Name, Book, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC) RN
   FROM yourTable
)
SELECT ID, Name, Book
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/56e4f/1)**